# How to upload image after every 3 seconds using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

In html page input type is **file**. Simply I can upload image. But I want to add image after 3 seconds manually. And that image folder is in my local System. It should read folder and upload to the cloud.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="method-test">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><h4>recognize() Method</h4>
            <form id="recognizeForm">
                Image (public URL or base64 data): <input type="text" class="image" name="Image">
              Image (local file): <input type="file" class="image-upload" name="Image Upload">
                Gallery Name: <input type="text" class="gallery_name" name="Gallery Name">
                <input type="button" id="testRecognize" value="Test" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this code for manually added image in file.

Comment: using javascript no you can't but using ajax+php yes you can

Comment: use [settimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: you mean setInterval() :-)

Comment: ok but How to laod from local system and pass to in div tag. @Gerfried

Comment: if you write-over the same file each time, then you can simply re-FileReader() it and FormData()+ajax it out

Comment: Can you please help us understand, are you looking for probing the local folder for any changes / addition of files? And when that happens you want to execute JavaScript to upload the same to a given Url.

Comment: @CharanrajGolla , We have network camera. From that camera in every 3 seconds we capture  image . So I need to upload that image in every 3 seconds. In above code I can add one image manually.

Comment: You can't upload an image from any device via a browser without the user explicitly, manually, selecting the file. Browser is a user tool. If you want some automated process, use a different process (e.g. automated service on the device which takes a photo and then sends it to the server via a HTTP request or other transmission method)

Comment: @ADyson , Can I use setInterval function

Comment: What? No. Read what I wrote more carefully. You can't do this from a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setInterval function

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```